# How to query a DynamoDB table and order results by primary key?

Tags: sorting, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a DynamoDB table where each item has 4 attributes: timestamp, message, category and status. The table was set up with timestamp as the (simple) primary key.

I want to be able to query the table for all items with a particular category and status, so I set up a global secondary index on category and status, and that's working as I want.

But how can I get the results of the query in order of timestamp? I thought it would have something to do with `ScanIndexForward`, but that only seems to apply to the table's sort key, which my table doesn't have.

Comment: As you mentioned, dynamodb doesn't have a feature to sort the result based on any attributes other than sort key. So, it has to be done at client side (i.e. can't be achieved using the dynamodb api).

Comment: @notionquest Imagine I want to paginate the items, in pages of 10, in order. Does that mean I have to query the table for all items (requesting potentially thousands/millions of items), sort them, and then perform the query again for the next page of items?

Comment: Yes, for the above question. The better things is to remodel your data structure i.e. use some other attribute as partition key and keep timestamp as sort key. I have come across many data models which use timestamp as sort key and it worked well.